# Unable to get to the home screen or login

Tags: mount, login

Initially I started to upgrade my ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04. 
I failed for some reason.

```
Error: filesystem check or mount failed
```

Commands I ran:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
```

Then I forced a restart by pressing the power button.

Now I am unable to login with my correct password and Guest Session is also not able to work, it was without a password.

Urgent help required.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Display Manager do you use? Have you tried to reconfigure it? you can do so by using the command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` for the one you are using.

Maybe hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to change to console mode and using the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that, maybe `sudo service lightdm restart` or `sudo service gdm restart` could get you back to what you are looking for.

Comment: I am a new user to ubuntu.

Comment: starkus, You can always edit the post. no need for extra comments

Comment: When  I press Alt + Ctrl + F1 I reach to a screen where it says :Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Deepak tty1,   Deepak login:_

Comment: NOw here when I enter my correct username and password then it says Login incorrect.   What do I do now?

Comment: Can you help me to reach the command line?

Comment: I tried all the steps as mentioned changed my password . now I ran one more command "sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus" after this I restarted my system. now  as i have entered in my  password i reached to a black screen with a cursor.

Comment: I have now tried a command "sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* and sudo reboot" I am now not getting a black screen but my wallpaper. No icons on my desktop screen. I am not sure I have logged in or not but the screen is all blank just my cursor moves on.